# C++ explicit type is missing('int' assumed)3

Tags: c++

[image]

Under the display() and evaluate() I get an error code saying that the explicit type is missing('int' assumed).
I'm stuck on this part and I'm wondering how I could fix this, would appreciate any assistance.

```
#pragma warning
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class poly {
    int degree;
    int* coeff;

public:
    poly(int);
    poly(poly&);
    poly();
    ~poly();
    display();
    evaluate(int);
    poly operator+(poly&);
    poly operator*(poly&);
};
```

Comment: you should read a c++ book

Comment: you should also indent your code correctly, so that it's actually readable.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't done c++ in a while(have been doing java a lot more), I'm trying to brush up on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
display();
```

write

```
void display();
```

And ditto for `evaluate`.

---

Tip: you can use free tools like AStyle to format your code with proper indenting.

Tip: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) provides a nice list of C++ textbooks.

Comment: Yes, that worked, I feel like an idiot. Thank you so much.